# send_mail is clearly sending email but no email is showing up in inbox

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, email, webserver

I have these email settings in my `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@myemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

and am using this function to send email to recipients.

```
def send_email(subject, body, recipients, agent_email, bcc=[], attachments=[]):
    recipient_list = []
    if isinstance(recipients, (str, unicode,)):
        recipient_list.append(recipients)
    else:
        recipient_list = recipients

    recipient_list = recipient_list + bcc

    send_mail(subject, body, settings.EMAIL_FROM, recipient_list)
```

while it looks quite clear when I go to the `django-admin` site that the email was indeed sent and no error messages show in the log files whatsoever, when I go to check the email that it was sent to, nothing shows in the inbox. I would expect to see the email there, especially given that it shows as sent in `django-admin`. Have I misunderstood something about how email is sent from the system?

**EDIT**

I also checked my spam folder and added

```
EMAIL_FROM = 'email@myemail.com'
```

because I noticed it wasn't there before. Same results, though. Email appears sent according to `django-admin` but no email in my inbox.

Comment: Check your spam folder. This is where mine first showed up.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion, but I already checked there. Should have put that fact in my question. Sorry.

Comment: check also your `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting.

Comment: Please ensure the EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD you have given are valid.

Comment: @GwynBleidD It appears as though there isn't one! I didn't set this up. I assume it's necessary. What should that setting be set to

Comment: Default value is just SMTP connection so it should work fine. Make sure that SMTP server properly accepts your message.

Comment: @GwynBleidD Thanks for responding. How do I make sure of that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'    
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: It appears as though that didn't work. I appreciate the effort.